# Can only reach my application on HTTP not HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, traefik, traefik-ingress, cert-manager

***update***

I did

**kubectl get ingressroute -A**

```
NAMESPACE NAME AGE

example example-ingress 44h

example example-ingress-route 40h
```

and then I did

**kubectl delete ingress example-ingress -n example**

```
ingress.extensions "example-ingress" deleted
```

and now http://example.com gives 404

but https://example.com works fine with secured cert and all?

I have a cluster where I have a simple dockerized php app that just displays “hello” on the page.

In the cluster I have installed traefik and cert-manager via their helm charts, as I am using cert-manager for lets encrypt:

https://hub.helm.sh/charts/traefik/traefik

https://hub.helm.sh/charts/jetstack/cert-manager

When I visit my domain via http it works and I can see **“hello”**

But when I visit my domain with https it just says **“404 page not found”**

---

Error in the traefik pod:

```
E0916 10:48:39.456348       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1alpha1.IngressRoute: v1alpha1.IngressRouteList.Items: []v1alpha1.IngressRoute: v1alpha1.IngressRoute.Spec: v1alpha1.IngressRouteSpec.TLS: readObjectStart: expect { or n, but found [, error found in #10 byte of ...|}],"tls":[{"hosts":[|..., bigger context ...|ices":[{"name":"example-app","port":80}]}],"tls":[{"hosts”:[“example.com"],"secretName|...
```

---

When I click the https shield on the browser and click more information it informs me:

```
Verified by: CN=TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
DNS Name 31047792e374617b441b6f82cacde627.1dc1fc2f960b83b2f533f2ff411e82bf.traefik.default
```

---

For setting up cert-manager I followed most of this guide:
https://opensource.com/article/20/3/ssl-letsencrypt-k3s

---

When I do:

**kubectl get issuers -n example**

```
NAME                     READY   AGE
example-issuer-staging   True    15h
```

---

When I do:

**kubectl get certificates -n example**

```
NAME                            READY   SECRET                          AGE
domain-com       True    domain-com-tls   15h
```

---

When I do a curl on http and https here are my results:

**curl -v http://example.com**

```
*   Trying domain-ip…
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (domain-ip) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Tue, 15 Sep 2020 15:41:45 GMT
< Server: nginx
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.9
< Content-Length: 5
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
hello* Closing connection 0
```

**curl -v https://example.com**

```
*   Trying domain-ip...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (domain-ip) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

---

When I do:

**kubectl get secret -n example**

```
NAME                                  TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
domain-com-tls         kubernetes.io/tls                     2      19h
```

---

When I do:

**kubectl get ing -A**

```
NAMESPACE   NAME              CLASS    HOSTS                       ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
example     example-ingress   <none>   example.com             80, 443   13d
```

---

When I do:

**kubectl get svc -A**

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)                      AGE
cert-manager   cert-manager           ClusterIP      10.245.95.66     <none>            9402/TCP                     16h
cert-manager   cert-manager-webhook   ClusterIP      10.245.86.7      <none>            443/TCP                      16h
default        kubernetes             ClusterIP      10.245.0.1       <none>            443/TCP                      23d
example        example-app            ClusterIP      10.245.132.184   <none>            80/TCP,443/TCP               15m
kube-system    kube-dns               ClusterIP      10.245.0.10      <none>            53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       23d
routing        traefik                LoadBalancer   10.245.21.52     external-ip   80:31635/TCP,443:31142/TCP   2d1
```

---

When I do:

**kubectl describe certificates domain-com -n example**

```
Name:         domain-com
Namespace:    example
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-09-15T17:41:27Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:conditions:
        f:notAfter:
        f:notBefore:
        f:renewalTime:
    Manager:      controller
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2020-09-15T17:41:27Z
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:commonName:
        f:dnsNames:
        f:issuerRef:
          .:
          f:kind:
          f:name:
        f:secretName:
    Manager:         kubectl
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2020-09-15T17:41:27Z
  Resource Version:  2018179
  Self Link:         /apis/cert-manager.io/v1/namespaces/example/certificates/domain-com
  UID:               1ddb2c20-0fa5-414b-af4f-32c4e02cf41f
Spec:
  Common Name:  example.com
  Dns Names:
    example.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Kind:       Issuer
    Name:       example-issuer
  Secret Name:  domain-com-tls
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2020-09-15T17:41:27Z
    Message:               Certificate is up to date and has not expired
    Reason:                Ready
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
  Not After:               2020-12-14T12:11:24Z
  Not Before:              2020-09-15T12:11:24Z
  Renewal Time:            2020-11-14T12:11:24Z
Events:                    <none>
```

---

When I do:

**kubectl describe pods -n example example-app-main-g9tzn**

```
Name:         example-app-main-g9tzn
Namespace:    example
Priority:     0
Node:         cluster-name-3gkmj/10.110.0.5
Start Time:   Wed, 16 Sep 2020 11:16:06 +0200
Labels:       app=example-app
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.0.75
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.75
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/example-app-main
Containers:
  example-app-container:
    Container ID:   docker://bede3ad52bc2d54d343bd0c8ec36ad39854b65e97522f9e0153b6d33f18d05bf
    Image:          richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:1.10.3
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://richarvey/nginx-php-fpm@sha256:140e92581255ce5e19d144b883560fa891a632fedaf68910ba4b65550d5b12a5
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 16 Sep 2020 11:16:10 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      SSH_KEY:    secret
      GIT_REPO:   login-details:project-name/source.git
      GIT_EMAIL:  user@example.com
      GIT_NAME:   user
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-bphcm (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-bphcm:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-bphcm
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                                   Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                                   -------
  Normal  Scheduled  21m   default-scheduler                      Successfully assigned example/example-app-main-g9tzn to cluster-3gkmj
  Normal  Pulling    21m   kubelet, cluster-3gkmj Pulling image "richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:1.10.3"
  Normal  Pulled     21m   kubelet, cluster-3gkmj  Successfully pulled image "richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:1.10.3"
  Normal  Created    21m   kubelet, cluster-3gkmj  Created container example-app-container
  Normal  Started    21m   kubelet, cluster-3gkmj  Started container example-app-container
```

---

When I do:

**kubectl describe deployment traefik  -n routing**

```
Name:                   traefik
Namespace:              routing
CreationTimestamp:      Sun, 13 Sep 2020 18:14:53 +0200
Labels:                 app.kubernetes.io/instance=traefik
                        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                        app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik
                        helm.sh/chart=traefik-9.1.1
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
                        meta.helm.sh/release-name: traefik
                        meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: routing
Selector:               app.kubernetes.io/instance=traefik,app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  1 max unavailable, 1 max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=traefik
                    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik
                    helm.sh/chart=traefik-9.1.1
  Service Account:  traefik
  Containers:
   traefik:
    Image:       traefik:2.2.8
    Ports:       9000/TCP, 8000/TCP, 8443/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      --global.checknewversion
      --global.sendanonymoususage
      --entryPoints.traefik.address=:9000/tcp
      --entryPoints.web.address=:8000/tcp
      --entryPoints.websecure.address=:8443/tcp
      --api.dashboard=true
      --ping=true
      --providers.kubernetescrd
      --providers.kubernetesingress
      --accesslog=true
      --accesslog.fields.defaultmode=keep
      --accesslog.fields.headers.defaultmode=drop
    Liveness:     http-get http://:9000/ping delay=10s timeout=2s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    http-get http://:9000/ping delay=10s timeout=2s period=10s #success=1 #failure=1
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /data from data (rw)
      /tmp from tmp (rw)
  Volumes:
   data:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
   tmp:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   traefik-7bfff8d8f6 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

---

I am trying to figure out what is going wrong, so any help would be great!

Here is my file structure for my php app:

```
example
- example-ingress-route.yml
- example-app.yml
- example-issuer.yml
- example-service.yml
- example-solver.yml
```

---

Content of:
**example-ingress-route.yml**

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  namespace: example
  name: example-ingress-route
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
  cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: example-issuer
  traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web, websecure
  traefik.frontend.redirect.entryPoint: https
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`example.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: example-app
          namespace: example
          port: 443
  tls:
    hosts:
      - example.com
    options:
      namespace: example
    secretName: domain-com-tls
```

---

Content of:
**example-app.yml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  namespace: example
  name: 'example-app-main'
  labels:
    app: 'example-app'
    tier: 'frontend'
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: 'example-app'
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: 'example-app'
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: example-app-container
        image: richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:1.10.3 
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: SSH_KEY
            value: ‘hidden’
          - name: GIT_REPO
            value: 'git@gitlab.example.com:project//source.git'
          - name: GIT_EMAIL
            value: ‘hidden’
          - name: GIT_NAME
            value: ‘hidden’
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

---

Content of:
**example-issuer.yml**

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: example-issuer
  namespace: example
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server  URL
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: letsencrypt@example.com
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: domain-com-tls
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge  provider
    solvers:
    # An empty 'selector' means that this solver matches all domains
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: traefik
```

---

Content of:
**example-service.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: example
  name: 'example-app'
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - protocol: TCP
      name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: 'example-app'
```

---

Content of:
**example-solver.yml**

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: domain-com
  namespace: example
spec:
  secretName: domain-com-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: example-issuer
    kind: Issuer
  commonName: example.com
  dnsNames:
  - example.com
```

Comment: Are you creating certificate manually or is it created by Ingress Resource?

Comment: It is created with the Ingress Resource

Answer (score 0):

Some error in your YAMLs

1. In `example-ingress-route.yml`  you have `"cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: example-issuer"`

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  namespace: example
  name: example-ingress-route
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
  cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: example-issuer
```

But you have created a issuer in `example-issuer.yml`

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: example-issuer
  namespace: example
```

You can change to ClusterIssuers in `example-issuer.yml`

Comment: I just want the issuer as namespaced to example not the entire cluster. Can I just put cert-manager.io/issuer: example-issuer instead of cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: example-issuer? I thought the annotation just references to where I have created the issuer so to link them? Should I just delete that entire line in the annotation section?

Comment: No, It is either Issuer(works within a namespace) or ClusterIssuer.

Comment: I changed to cert-manager.io/issuer: example-issuer and kept example-issuer.yml to Issuer but I still have the same issue.

Comment: can you try changing `kind: IngressRoute` in example-ingress-route.yml to `kind: Ingress`

Comment: I originally had just Ingress, and it wasn't working then either (http was, not https). I changed as recommend on the traefik documentation to take advantage of the CRD way: https://docs.traefik.io/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/

Comment: update

I did

kubectl get ingressroute -A

NAMESPACE NAME AGE

example example-ingress 44h

example example-ingress-route 40h


and then I did

kubectl delete ingress example-ingress -n example

ingress.extensions "example-ingress" deleted


and now http example.com gives 404

but https example.com works fine with secured cert and all?